# Address database?

Tags: database

I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask this, but it goes.

I'm doing planning/research for a website that NEEDS a database of addresses for every home in the US. I don't need resident names or anything, just the address, city, zip, state, etc. I plan to interface with the Zillow api to get more details for each address per user request, but I need the address in the db for sitemap building and I will have more meta data that will reference these addresses.

Is there an API I could scrap this from or a public database of this somewhere reliable free or paid? Preferably with the ability to get updates!

Comment: The proper place to ask this **would** be the Data SE site, but it has not yet been created... http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37195/data

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://www.usps.com/business/webtools.htm (don't miss the list of service providers!)
or this: https://www.usps.com/business/address-information-systems.htm

Comment: I don't have an up to date link but I believe FedEx has address tools as well.

Answer (score 0):

personally I would look to Google for something like this, the might actually have a database of addresses that you could use.

I also found a website while I was searching, you might have already seen it, but it doesn't sounds like this is something that is a good idea unless you have a rather large DB

[US Address Database](http://www.groupsrv.com/computers/about685220.html)